# Why does "\9" give "9" while "\7" is empty?

Tags: javascript, string, lexical

I have read the lexical grammar of the String literals. I found out that both `"\9"` and `"\7"` are considered invalid string literals.
But why does `alert("\9")` give `9` while `alert("\7")` is empty (I expected `\7`)?

Answer (score 4):

`alert("\7")` doesn't give you an *empty* string, it gives you a string with character 7. This is because the browser you're testing it on extends the definition of a string literal to allow for octal character escapes, as described in [Section B.1.2 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.2).

Since `9` isn't an octal digit, `\9` doesn't get interpreted as an octal character escape sequence, and so the backslash is silently dropped.

Note that in a conforming implementation, if you were in strict mode, `alert("\7")` wouldn't work either, as you can see here with Chrome, Firefox, or another browser that supports strict mode: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ugutuz/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ugutuz/1/edit)

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  alert("\7"); // fails
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

`\7` is interpreted as an octal string and yields a single character with ASCII value 7. 9 does not fit in the octal base, hence it is interpreted as a regular character. The backslash is silently dropped as it does not have any side-effects.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings:

> `\XXX`    The character with the Latin-1 encoding specified by up to three octal digits `XXX` between `0` and `377`. For example, `\251` is the octal sequence for the copyright symbol.